# get different values from API calls

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks

I have this code for getting urls of images from faker API

```
var change = 1

useEffect(() => {

    async function get() {

        setloading(true)
        const i = await faker.image.fashion(120, 200)
        setimg(i)
        console.log(img)
        setloading(false)
    }
    get()
    

}, [change])
```

Below is the jsx code

```
<div className='box'>

            <h3>Latest Trends</h3>
            <
            <div className='details'>
                {loading ? ClipLoader color='#000000' loading={!loading} cssOverride={override} size={30} />
                 :
                 [1, 2, 3, 4].map(e => {
                    change = change + 1
                    console.log(change);
                    return (
                        <div className='img'>
                            <img src={img} alt="" />
                        </div>
                    )
                })}
            </div>

        </div>
```

as you can see in the above code I am trying to run a loop 4 times using map. I want to get a different image each time from the API for every time the loop executes. The problem is that I am getting same image url for all 4 times.

Basically, I want UseEffect to run every time the loop runs and give me a different API call each time. Also, fakers API returns random images on every API call.

Edit: If I use a state variable like this I am getting infinite renders.

```
[1, 2, 3, 4].map(e => {
                    setchange(change + 1)
                    console.log(change);
                    return (
                        <div className='img'>
                            <img src={img} alt="" />
                        </div>
                    )
                })
```

Comment: read about usestate as normal variables can't re-render your app when the data is loaded https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-state.html

Comment: `change = change + 1` is not doing anything

Comment: @uditkumar01 if I use useState in place of normal variable, it's causing infinite renders

Comment: @MohdZaid don't add the state variable in the dependency array. As adding it would cause infinite re-renders. Keep it empty if you want to fetch the data only once.

Answer (score 0):

If that fake API can't return a list of images, I think the better way to do it at least would be to fetch images 4 times(or any times you want) once(first render) in useEffect, and then save those returned images as an Array in state and then loop through that Array to display your images

Comment: That's one way to do it. But I wanted to trigger useEffect every time the loop executes.

Comment: What's your end goal? Cause what you're trying to do will always end in an infinite loop. Because you're triggering re-render inside render method. It's like the render method is calling itself all over again.

Answer (score 0):

here is simple html and js with cdn link of faker

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Document</title>
</head>

<body>
    <div id="app"></div>
    <script type="module">
        import { faker } from 'https://cdn.skypack.dev/@faker-js/faker';

        for (var i = 1; i <= 5; i++) {
            console.log(`${faker.image.fashion(120, 200, true)}`)
            let img = new Image();
            img.src = faker.image.nature(120, 200, true);
            document.getElementById('app').append(img)
        }
      </script>
      
</body>

</html>
```

mistake done by you.

1. no need to async function in useEffect.
2. simple use `useState` hook if you want to manage local state.
3. worst way to assing local variable from rendering `change = change + 1`.
4. use last `boolean` param in `faker` api for `random` image like `faker.image.fashion(120, 200, true)`

and here is stackblitz for react find.

`Faker image` button in below blitz and click on it you see loaded image with in sec.
https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-6ivxaj?file=src%2Ffaker%2FFaker.js